# Added Maven json-simple maven dependency, reloaded maven, still cant use the library in the project

Tags: java, json, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I have an issue where even if I add the dependency to the pom.xml and try importing the library it just shows errors. The dependency gets added, but I still cant use it in the classes. This is not my first maven project, nor my first time adding a dependency. I have other dependencies that work well. I have tried multiple json libraries, I have looked up a few questions here that have similar problems, but none seem to solve my issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.zoohandlung</groupId>
  <artifactId>Main</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ZoohandlungInfoLK</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>20</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
-The new added dependency:
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
-
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>20</source>
          <target>20</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.8</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Share the code showing which imports/classes you are trying to use. There are different JSON libraries and you may be using not the one you added to the dependencies.

Comment: Did you update `module-info.java`?

Comment: @SedJ601 I love you my guy, thank you so much. While I have worked with maven before, I had no idea what the module-info.java did. Thanks, it works now